# Adding a comma after each category

Tags: php

this seems like a pretty straight forward question and for some reason I am having trouble figuring out how to achieve what I am looking for.

```
$category = $html2->find('.video_cats',0);
$category = $genre->plaintext;


<div class="video_cats">
<span>Categories:</span>
    <a href="http://www.example.com" title="Example Category" class="video_cat">House</a>   
    <a href="http://www.example.com" title="Example Category" class="video_cat">The Cat</a> 
    <a href="http://www.example.com" title="Example Category" class="video_cat">Car</a> 
    <a href="http://www.example.com" title="Example Category" class="video_cat">The Dog</a>                                                             
</div>
```

Currently I have a string called `$category` if we `print` the results of this string it will return the following text ***One Two Three Four Five*** I am trying to make it so that it returns the text ***One, Two, Three, Four, Five***. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT :** 
This is the desired output 
***Category: A Cat, Dog, A Horse, House*** because some of the category names have spaces in them we can't just replace the spaces with commas.

Comment: How can we possibly know which categories have spaces in and which don't? Is there a list of all the categories somewhere? Where is your `$category` string coming from?

Comment: I agree with @MattRaines - with the given information this problem cannot be solved.

Comment: You will need to form this list with some delimiter around each category. For example: "A Cat" "Dog" "A Horse" "House" otherwise if it is only a space, no pattern is going to pick it up reliably. The only possibility would be if the preceding word  is something predictable such as: "A" or "The", then you could use regular expressions to match back on previous word being in a defined list, then include the next word as part of the match. But that could still be problematic.

Comment: How are you creating this string? If it came from an array or a database, you should be able to add the commas when you're constructing it in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar I am scraping this using simple_html_dom.php from another website, the string of categories will never be the same this is my issue currently.. I have tried numerous things with no luck.. I'm almost not 100% sure how to word this question.

Comment: Are they coming from different elements in the HTML? You should be able to put them into an array when you're scraping, instead of combining them into a single string.

Comment: Try creating a simple example with the html you are scraping and how you are storing the values.

Comment: @barmar I updated with the code I am using right now -> this returns only one result. the 0 is causing this to link the first result I am sure I need it to  pull all of the results for this to work with exploding the spaces.

Comment: What kind of element is `.video_cats`? Maybe it's a `<ul>` and the categories are in `<li>`. If you search for that it will return an array. Show the HTML.

Comment: @Barmar view update please I updated with a reference to the content I'm scraping currently.

Comment: Right, if you can capture/scrape the category items one at a time, you could easily store them into an array and then do whatever you want with them at that point. However, we need more of an example. Could you provide a simplified version of the HTML you are scraping (include something that would have multiple categories. And also provide as much of your javascript as possible showing how you scrape and store the data.

Comment: @gmiley I just did in the latest update

Comment: Perfect, just access the collection of `a` elements as an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for the anchors rather than the DIV, then you can loop over them and make an array.

```
$cat_array = array():
foreach ($html2->find(".video_cat") as $cat) {
    $cat_array[] = $cat->plaintext;
}

$category = implode(', ', $cat_array);
```

Comment: Thank you so much man, I don't know why I made this so complicated but it was giving me a very serious headache so I appreciate you heaps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `explode` and `implode` like this:

```
$category = implode(", ", explode(" ", $category));
```

Then just print out the new contents of `$category`.

After taking your edit into consideration, the above would not really work, however if you were to use `split` instead of `explode` you could use regular expressions to do a backreference match on a list of pre-defined words such as: "A", "The", etc... (See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html )

This could be a solution, but is still rather problematic. The best approach would be to find a way to delimit your list better.

Comment: OP edited the question, changing requirements, and therein invalidated your answer.